# Facing issues with sticky keys on M1 Pro 16"

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, apple-silicon

I live in Bengaluru, India and here are the weather details.

> 22°C 
> Precipitation: 6% 
> Humidity: 86% ~ mostly humid, goes upto 90% as
> well 
> Wind: 5 km/h

In the past, I had sticky issues with Enter key.

> It was taking much pressure to press and also there was no clicky
> feedback when pressed.

I visited iCare, and they cleaned the keys. After they were serviced all keys were fine.

Now, after one month, I started having the same issue with my *Left Shift Key.*

Someone suggest using a makeup brush and swiping under the keys to take out debris if there is any and I tried.
But debris wasn't the issue. I think it's most likely humidity.

- Should I visit iCare again?
- What can I do to prevent it in future?
- Is there anything wrong with the inbuilt keyboard? Should I ask for a replacement of the keyboard?
- Is there any safer way to fix it by myself?

I am new here, pardon for asking many questions in one post.

***Update:***

I visited iCare again and they cleaned it on the spot within two minutes.

I asked the receptionist about the issue and how they cleaned it.

She replied it was dust and the engineer used some blower to clean it.

***Thanks!***

Comment: Sounds like you have a lot of dust mixed with humidity.  You might want to look into some sort of keyboard cover as a preventative measure.

Comment: Sounds like a quality issue; those aren't particularly harsh environmental conditions. My suggestion would be to return it to Apple for a replacement if you can.

Comment: For now, they fixed it again using. They cleaned using some sort of blower. I couldn't ask for a replacement hence. If it happens again, I will definitely ask for a replacement. Luckily I have more than 6 months remaining warranty period.

Comment: @MarcelWilson I bought a keyboard cover and I only use it while using the laptop. When I am done with the work, I just take it off from screen to prevent any damage to the screen. Let's see if this works.